# Display the category based on product collection sort created for all category in magento

Tags: magento2

I need to display a category sorting based on product count sorting from high to low can anyone help me.

```
 public function getCategoryCollection(){

    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $collection = $category
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured',1)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying 'product count sorting'? Do you mean sorting by quantity in stock? Or you want to sort categories by number of products assigned to each category?

Comment: want to sort categories by number of products assigned to each category like 


Mens -50
Kids- 25
womens-10
default category -2

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the code below:

```
private $categoryCollectionFactory;

private $resourceConnection;

public function __construct(
    CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}

public function getCategoryCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $indexTable = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_category_product_index');

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            ['ccp' => $indexTable],
            'ccp.category_id = e.entity_id',
            ['product_count' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(product_id)')]
        )->group(
            'e.entity_id'
        )->order(
            'product_count DESC'
        );

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    
    return $collection;
}
```

This will count only the products that are actually visible in catalog (enabled, assigned to the website, correct visibility, etc.)